# duplicate "Authorized Applications" in Laravel passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I have created an Oauth2 server and consumer app in Laravel by following https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Repo URL: https://github.com/xparthx/Laravel-Passport---Oauth2

So far it is working fine.

The issue is when I'm assessing the Oauth2 server from the consumer app, it makes duplication for the same OAuth Client. (See **Authorized Applications** section in the attachment)

[image]

Steps to produce the bug:

1) Run consumer app in browser

2) Visit /redirect URL

3) Login into the site

4) Login into Oauth2 site and check the Authorized Applications sections (There will be a new entry for Consumer app)

Comment: Do you find the solution? I'm facing this bug right now...!

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: I found this https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/83 maybe this is only solution right now, I have tested, it works but database still mess :(

Comment: I have the same issue